# How can I implement a delay with Caliburn.Micro actions using a convention

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, caliburn.micro

I sometimes need to delay binding execution (think of a search box that calls the server, you'd want it to execute only if the user paused for a split second and not for every key stroke).

Delaying WPF bindings is no problem - you just specify the delay with the binding:
`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Delay=500}"/>`.

Whenever I need to delay execution in a situation where I use Caliburn.Micro's `Message.Attach`, I usually implement it this way (message is attached to the `TextChanged` event with the `DoSomething` action):

```
private int doingSomething;

public async void DoSomething()
{
    int current = ++doingSomething;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    if (current != doingSomething) //method was reentered
        return;

    await DoWorkCallServerEtc();
}
```

This works well, but it doesn't scale well and breaks the *DRY* principle (I need to write this again wherever I need the delay).

My question is, can I somehow write a convention for this using Caliburn.Micro?
Or maybe a different, more scalable approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation page](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)

> Actions feature leverages System.Windows.Interactivity for it's
>   trigger mechanism.

It means that

```
<TextBox Name="textBox" Margin="5"
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event TextChanged] = [Action DoAction(textBox.Text)]" />
```

is equivalent to:

```
<TextBox Margin="5" Name="textBox">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="DoAction">
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text}" />
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

The object which is responsible for executing the `DoAction` method is the [EventTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.eventtrigger(v=expression.40).aspx). An `EventTrigger` triggers immediatelly, with no delay. So we need to create your own `DelayedEventTrigger`; something like that:

```
public class DelayedEventTrigger : System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger
{
    private EventArgs args;
    private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Delay", typeof(int), typeof(DelayedEventTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(1000));

    public int Delay
    {
        get { return (int)base.GetValue(DelayProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(DelayProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnEvent(EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (dispatcherTimer != null)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        }
        args = eventArgs;
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Delay);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnDispatcherTimerTick);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        if (dispatcherTimer != null)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            dispatcherTimer = null;
        }
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnDispatcherTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        InvokeActions(args);
    }
}
```

Its default delay is 1 second (1000 milliseconds). So now we can use it in our XAML:

```
<TextBox Margin="5" Name="textBox">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <local:DelayedEventTrigger Delay="800" EventName="TextChanged">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="DoDelayAction">
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text}" />
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </local:DelayedEventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

In my opinion there's no need to use conventions (you can use the `DelayedEventTrigger` explicitly), but if you want you can configure the Caliburn Parser in your `Bootstrapper` class:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    base.Configure();

    Parser.CreateTrigger = delegate(DependencyObject target, string triggerText)
    {
        System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger eventTrigger;
        if (triggerText == null)
        {
            ElementConvention elementConvention = ConventionManager.GetElementConvention(target.GetType());
            return elementConvention.CreateTrigger();
        }
        string eventName = triggerText.Replace("[", String.Empty).Replace("]", String.Empty);
        if (eventName.StartsWith("Delayed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            eventName = eventName.Replace("DelayedEvent", String.Empty).Trim();
            eventTrigger = new DelayedEventTrigger();
        }
        else
        {
            eventName = eventName.Replace("Event", String.Empty).Trim();
            eventTrigger = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
        }

        eventTrigger.EventName = eventName;
        return eventTrigger;
    };     
}
```

By adding this code you can use this convention:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox" Margin="5"
    cal:Message.Attach="[DelayedEvent TextChanged] = [Action DoDelayAction(textBox.Text)]" />
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I'm speechless.. thanks!  I especially like how you begin by *In my opinion there's no need to use conventions..* and then BOOM *here's a convention anyway..* :-)